# htaccess environment variable based on query string without some pamameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

I want set a apache environment variable based on query string variable but without some parameters.

for example, i have this query string:

```
utm_source=foo&my_param=baz&utm_medium=bar&_t=9999
```

now, i want set a variable without `utm_source` and `utm_medium`:

```
my_param=baz&_t=9999
```

i know only the parameters to remove (`utm_source` & `utm_medium`)... the other are only an example...

i have wtrite this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%{QUERY_STRING}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*)&?(utm_source|utm_medium)=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%3]
```

the output is

```
utm_source=foo&my_param=baz&_t=9999
```

why utm_source param persist?

i have also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%{QUERY_STRING}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*)&?utm_source=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%2]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*)&?utm_medium=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%2]
```

the output is right!

```
a=b&my_param=baz&_t=9999
```

i don't undertand why this version not work!

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*)&?(utm_source|utm_medium)=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*)&?(utm_source|utm_medium)=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
```

doesn't remove both `utm_source` *and* `utm_medium`, because it matches only *one* of them.

`.*` matches the longest possible string, including one of `utm_source` or `utm_medium`, whichever comes first. See also [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), especially section [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) and following, for a detailed explanation.

`utm_source|utm_medium` means in plain english: match either `utm_source` *or* `utm_medium`. So the regular expression matches

```
(.*)                          - %1, including utm_source
(utm_source|utm_medium)=[^&]+ - utm_medium=...
(.*)                          - %3, everything else after utm_medium
```

---

The second variant with two conditions and rules works, because first you remove `utm_source=...`, and then pass the remaining string to the second condition. There the `utm_medium=...` part is removed, and finally you have the desired string without both `utm_source` and `utm_medium`.

---

You may enclose the test string with `&`s. This guarantees, that you have always an ampersand before and after the `utm_source=...` part and allows to simplify the regular expression a little bit.

```
RewriteCond &%{ENV:CustomQueryString}& ^(.*)&utm_source=.+?&(.*)$ [NC]
```

Same goes for the second `RewriteCond` with `utm_medium`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It is possible fix the first rule? The first rule has less code and more readable...

Comment: You may use something like `(.*)&(?:utm_source|utm_medium)...(.*)...(?:utm_source|utm_medium)...&(.*)` and have `%1%2%3` as a result, but this only matches, if you have always both arguments present. Your two rule solution looks like it is the optimum.

Comment: No problem, just keep on improving :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rule to remove both query parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%{QUERY_STRING}]

# remove utm_source from query string and set env var
RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*&)?utm_source=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%2]

# remove utm_medium from query string and reset env var
RewriteCond %{ENV:CustomQueryString} ^(.*&)?utm_medium=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=CustomQueryString:%1%2]
```

If we start with URL as `/?utm_source=foo&my_param=baz&utm_medium=bar&_t=9999`

After 2nd rule we will have:

```
$_SERVER["CustomQueryString"] becomes `my_param=baz&_t=9999`
```

Comment: but if QUERY_STRING not contains utm_source, env CustomQueryString are not set and second rule fail?

Comment: You wrote `i know only the parameters to remove (utm_source & utm_medium)`. That gives an impression that query string will have both of these parameters. If not please clarify

Comment: btw the rule you've shown in question is totally correct. Test that with `/?myutm_source=foo&my_param=baz&utm_medium=bar&_t=9999` and `CustomQueryString` will be set to `mymy_param=baz&_t=9999`